# How to create session http in pl/sql

Tags: session, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I work on project in pl/sql and need to secure a part of a website by login form.
I wrote package UI to show authentication(login, password) form and other forms. But how can I create  an user session if the login and password are correct and show the logged view ??

Comment: Are you using mod_plsql for your web application?

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk yes I use mod_plsql for my web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own table in the database to store session related information:

```
create table web_sessions(
  session_id varchar2(32)
, variable varchar2(32)
, value varchar2(4000)
);
```

Use [DBMS_RANDOM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_random.htm#ARPLS040) to generate a random string as session identifier and use [OWA_COOKIE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/w_cook.htm#ARPLS387) to store it in a cookie.

Your login page should do:

1. Set session cookie with random string
2. Check username/password
3. If username/password are correct, store successful login in your session table
4. Redirect to main application page

Every page in your application should check:

1. Get the session cookie
2. If session does not exist (or is not valid), redirect to login page
3. Show authenticated content

This should get you going.